# Typing a dictionary to contain subclasses but not parent class

Tags: python

I've got a dictionary, `name_to_class`, that maps a string to one of several subclasses of an Abstract class. The string is read in by my program, and tells the program which class to use.

If `A` and `B` are *the only* subclasses of `Abstract`, I want to type `name_to_class` in a manner so that any indexed values are correctly inferred to be of type `A | B`.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from abc import ABCMeta

class Abstract(metaclass=ABCMeta): ...

class A(Abstract): ...

class B(Abstract): ...

name_to_class: dict[str, type[A] | type[B]] = {"A": A, "B": B}
a = name_to_class["A"]()

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(a)
    # type of a is A | B, which is desired!
    # but typing out `type[A] | type[B]` is overhead?
```

But in reality I have many classes, A-Z, and their names are much longer than represented here, so typing out `A | B | C...` feels like a lot of overhead. Is there a better way?

Since specifying the parent class as the type also allows any subclass, I first tried to see if mypy/pylance would recognise that I won't be instantiating my abstract class, but rather one of the children. No such luck however (this also feels like it wouldn't strictly be correct).

```py
name_to_class2: dict[str, type[Abstract]] = {"A": A, "B": B}
a2 = name_to_class2["A"]()

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(a2)
    # type of a is Abstract, which should never be the final type
```

I then decided to try a `TypeVar`, since I've seen them used to refer to any subclasses of a parent class, but this lacks a context.

```py
from typing import TypeVar

U = TypeVar("U", bound=Abstract)

name_to_class3: dict[str, type[U]] = {"A": A, "B": B}
#                              ^- Type variable "U" has no meaning in this context


a3 = name_to_class2["A"]()

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(a3)
    # type of a is Abstract, which should never be the final type
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Just go with `Abstract`. Sure, it's never going to be the concrete type of the object, but that's totally normal. Annotations *aren't expected* to be the concrete type of an object, and we use plenty of annotations that can't be the concrete type.

Comment: Besides, mypy doesn't know the full list of subclasses of your class. There could always be some other file somewhere it doesn't know about that makes another subclass.

Comment: I would just bite the bullet and type it out. You can still write something like `CC = Union[type[A], type[B]` (`CC = type[A] | type[B]` does not work), so you only have to do it *once*.

Comment: To do what you want, you would probably need support for invariant types (`Type[X]` is *covariant*, including `X` and its subclasses; you'd want something like `InvariantType[X]` to specify `X` and `X` alone) as well as support for negation types (so you could write something like `Type[Abstract] - InvariantType[Abstract]`: `Abstract` and its subclasses, minus `Abstract` itself.)

Comment: (Or just something like `ProperSubclasses[Abstract]`, to wrap all the type-theoretic nonsense up in one opaque type hint :) )

Comment: `Type[A|B]` is also allowed in place of `Type[A] | Type[B]`, cutting down on the amount of typing a little.

Comment: @chepner: Huh. I would have expected a subtle difference there - I would have expected `Type[A|B]` to allow `A|B` where `Type[A] | Type[B]` wouldn't - but mypy seems to treat `Type[A|B]` as `Type[A] | Type[B]` when I test it. I wonder if that's a bug.

Comment: The subtle difference is that `A|B` is not a type, only a type hint, so `Type[A] | Type[B]` is really the only sensible interpretation.